# Postgresql - How to convert one timestamp to another timestamp with its closer hour?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, postgresql-9.2

I have the following timestamp value : `2013-10-09 12:15:55.724+02`

I would like to have this instead : `2013-10-09 12:00:00.000+02`

I have tried the following :

```
to_char(creation, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:00:00.000')
```

How can I format the timezone ? `TZ` or `tz` are not good since they return `CEST` and `cest` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select date_trunc('hour', '2013-10-09 12:15:55.724+02'::timestamptz);
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer !

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [DATE_TRUNC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) function.